# Yii web service authorization and session

Tags: web-services, session, authorization, yii

What are the different authorization and session related measures that should be taken into account when using Yii web services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ATM I can just think of some security tokens used in connection with database (tokens are stored in DB and checked with the token placed in request, additionally you can store some more info)

Comment: Thanks..Yes, I have used tokens before on a non-Yii webservice, but was wondering if i could make use of Yii session variables and not use security tokens.